# How do I evaluate from a textarea?

Tags: php, html, forms

here's what I tried:

```
<form method="POST" action="new.php">
     <font color="#C0C0C0"><small>It doesn't highlight it but it still works. And feel free to resize it!</small></font><br />
     <textarea name="high" class="prettyprint">Insert code here</textarea><br />
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit">Debug</button>
     </form>
     </center>

     <h1>Debug Info:</h1>
     <pre><?php if(isset($_POST['high'])){

    $high = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? stripslashes($_POST['high']) : $_POST['high'];

    eval($high);    

      }?></pre>
```

I need it to evaluate the code from the textarea so it executes the PHP code (i put echo 'hi' in the textarea and it gives this error:) `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/a3827523/public_html/new.php(44) : eval()'d code on line 1`

I don't know what is the problem but can someone help?

Comment: [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/api) has an API and already invested the time in something like this (as well as the necessary checks that go in to place with allowing user-executed code).

Comment: no.... that's not it @brad

Comment: Well, `eval()`ing any code the user types in is **extremely dangerous**. It's not a matter of "that's not it", but more "that should be it".

Comment: I know. that's why i'm using this for private use

Comment: use `echo htmlspecialchars( $high )` before passing to `eval`

Comment: It might be worth considering that this is just some sort of administrative PHP console. Obviously, ensure you have all the right securities when doing that...

Comment: eval() code doesn't need php tag "<?php ?>", try to write code directly in the textarea

Comment: @user2550778, your code works perfectly well here. Using PHP 5.4.15. Must be something in your environment. INI settings, perhaps?

Comment: @user: Just make a PHP page, upload it to your host (or, better yet, install PHP locally with WAMP or something) and run it. There's no good reason for even having that kind of power be available externally.

Comment: @user2550778 sorry for my poor english. what's your input of $high? I mean that $high does not have to contain PHP Opening tags.

Comment: @屾顶洞人 yeah but then it wouldn't work. it would just say  if(isset($_POST['high'])){

    $high = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? stripslashes($_POST['high']) : $_POST['high'];

    eval($high);

Comment: I got it…… Semicolon missing

Comment: No I put a semicolon and it STILL doesn't work. same parse error @屾顶洞人

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (i put echo 'hi' in the textarea and it gives this error:)

because you miss a ";" at the end of line

--

additional：
I tried your code in my environment, got the same error in these two case below:

***Case 1*** in textarea begin code with php tag:

```
<?php
    echo 'hi'; 
?>
```

php manual wrote:

> mixed eval ( string $code_str )
>
> > The code string to be evaluated. code_str does not have to contain PHP
> >     Opening tags.

***Case 2*** some syntax error code in textarea:

```
echo 'hi'
```

semicolon missing.

Comment: Actually it worked! I'm not supposed to use <?php tags in the textarea since it's already there but. here's what I did. a loop and it showed the code that was in the textarea. how do i delete something. for exampple I put `echo "hi";` it does this: `echo "hi";hi` ...

Comment: @user2550778 the comment above has been completed?I'm afraid that i havn't understand yet.